# For a Multithreading program, if one thread dies how you can know that ?

Tags: linux, multithreading, unix, thread-safety, pthreads

For a Multithreading program, if one thread dies how you can know that ?

My idea:

(1) use ps to check LWP but it is manually, not efficient. 
(2) set a try-catch in each thread, if it exit non-normally, catch it.
(3) let the dying-thread send a message to std::cout or main thread.

Other better ideas ?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `pthread_cleanup_push(3)` at a very early stage in the thread function. The function given to `pthread_cleanup_push` could set some flag which a "watcher" thread can pick up. `pthread_cleanup_push` is also honoured by `pthread_exit` and is not bound to exceptions.

**Edit**: A second way to do this: Use `pthread_key_create(3)` with a destructor function and call `pthread_setspecific(3)` early in the thread function. The destructor function can signal the watching thread it's imminent death.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use pthread_cleanup_push and pthread_cleanup_pop to execute a cleanup handler on thread exit. This would catch cancellation/pthread_exit events.